# Angular 6 Routing Ignore API calls from routing

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have Angular 6 app and WebAPI. I have Deployed Angular app on IIS and beneath the Angular application I have created Application for API.

Something likes this

```
IIS 
  |
  |-Angular6App(port:443)
       |
       |-ServiceAPI
```

The Idea behind this is to use same DNS. So when https://Angular6App.com is called it should load angular app. If https://Angular6App.com/ServiceApi/api/cntlr/id is called it should get data(meaning call api service).

So now when I call https://Angular6App.com/ServiceApi/api/cntlr/id it is loading default route from angular app. Actually I want to skip angular routing when api is called.

Routing in Angular App

```js
[
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'A', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'A', component: AComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'B', component: BComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
]
```

Please let me know if I can do this way and how?

Thanks
--cc

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: i think its a good technique to deploy angular production static files with Web Api, as i have deployed angular application with spring boot and express as well, both jave their unique ways to deploy static files with their deployment. And we have to just copy the files generated by building angular app via ng build —prod, ie files from dist folder to this static area of speingboot or express

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined in your app? It feels like you have one that matches the `**` path and uses the default route's component or redirects to the default route.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I do not have any other routes specified except {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent}.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I did copied from dist. API and angular works when it is deployed as different sites/application. Problem is when I create API app under Angular in IIS.(redirects to default route when calling API)

Comment: have you perfectly balanced base-href in index.html ?

Comment: Yeah,  <base href="/">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.
ON IIS, Use URL rewrite to ignore the pattern of serviceapi.

Set a URL rewrite on the main application(top-level i.e.., Angular6App) to ignore any URL which matches */ServiceAPI

[Screenshot of URL rewrite setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWFHD.png)

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: You may also want to add the rule to the angular web.config:  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/ServiceApi" negate="true" />