# Angular + .Net Core - Production only routing problem when calling API from a browser

Tags: .net, angular, api, .net-core, url-routing

I have this weird problem that when I am waiting 30+ seconds before I do a browser API call it says the following message.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/tcform/GetCurrentDate' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/tcform/GetCurrentDate'     at Jt.noMatchError (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:265122)     at o.selector (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:264852)     at o.error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:894743)     at o._error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884678)     at o.error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884475)     at o._error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884678)     at o.error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884475)     at F._error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884678)     at F.error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884475)     at I._error (https://mysite/main.3a68a3e49f0763cc89ec.js:1:884678)
```

Example
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsl3J.png)

Example [Not Working and giving me the above error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbuWk.png)

If I am on the period within those 30 seconds it is working consistently. This is something that haunts me for a month now. Does anyone know what could be the issue of this behavior and how I can resolve it?

**Details are below.**

- Happens only on Production build
- It is hosted on IIS
- I make the production build with "npm run build -- --configuration production" then I copy the dist folder contents on the wwwroot. Then I publish from VS2019 and copy the published content to my server IIS.
- I am not using a hash strategy and I do not intend to, but I tried it and I still had the same issue.

I will post my Startup.cs...if you require any other files to determine I will try and provide them

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MotoYdrogiosVS.Repository;
using MotoYdrogiosVS.Middleware;
using MotoYdrogiosVS.Services.DataProtector;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddSingleton<IGlobalVariablesRepository, GlobalVariablesRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IProtectorService, ProtectorService>();

            //var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            //var cipher = provider.GetService<IProtectorService>();

            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationRepository, AuthenticationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ITcAccountsRepository, TcAccountsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IErrorRepository, ErrorRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPriceTableRepository, PriceTableRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IReportsRepository, ReportsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ITcDriverFormRepository, TcDriverFormRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ITcFormRepository, TcFormRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IVehiclesMakeRepository, VehiclesMakeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IJCCRepository, JCCRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISystemRepository, SystemRepository>();

            //services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();


            //commented out by charis at 27/6/2022
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddMvcCore();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
                //configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddSession();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {

                //app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                //{



                //    await next();

                //    if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"))
                //    {
                //        await next();
                //    }

                //    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !System.IO.Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                //    {
                //        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                //        await next();
                //    }
                //});

                app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.

                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {

                    //var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

                    //if (url.Contains("/api/tcform/GetCurrentDate"))
                    //{
                    //    // ...do your things
                    //    context.Response.Redirect(url, permanent: false);
                    //    return;   // short circuit
                    //}


                    await next();
                    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !System.IO.Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
             !context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"))
                    {
                        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                        await next();
                    }
                });

                app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseStaticFiles();

           //app.UseDefaultFiles();
           app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseDefaultFiles();
            //app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            //{
            //    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            //    {
            //        if (context.File.Name == "index.html")
            //        {
            //            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
            //            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
            //        }
            //    }
            //});

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseMvc();
                //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/"); // <-- added to redirect to angular
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                    {
                        var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                        {
                            Public = true,
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                        };

                    }
                });
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
                        var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                        {
                            Public = true,
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                        };
                    }
                };
                //spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsure why this could be happening, can you please try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012022/2435473)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sadly that was one of the first things I tried but had no success. I am not experienced with url rewriting so I might have not done it correctly but I tried some hours on it.

Answer (score 0):

After a month of researching I finally found my issue.

There was this code in my app.module.ts

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: environment.production,
  // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
  // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
  registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
})
```

I do not know what it is, it was from the template I used most likely but it was the issue of all my problems. I commented it out for now but it seems my web app works fine without it.